# How to make sticky header in a webshop

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have bought a webshop and wanted to make a sticky header so it stays on top all the time but none of solutions are working and I don't really know what to do now. Maybe somebody have an idea how can I make it work ( maybe I use wrong document or something) 
Here is the code for "main header"

```
    <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel1 block_uCVH2J xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0">
    <% $breakpoint_xs=12 $breakpoint_sm=12 $breakpoint_md=12 $viewport_xs=100 $viewport_sm=100 $viewport_md=100 %>
        <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel2 block_AJb3AWSz72yYqkKu4Hxs xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0 container">
            <% $breakpoint_xs=12 $breakpoint_sm=12 $breakpoint_md=12 $viewport_xs=100 $viewport_sm=100 $viewport_md=100 %>
                <div class="LayoutWrapper">
                    <div class="HorizontalContainer LayoutContainer level3 row containerlevel3 block_A2uGW9wfh3chajRB1xUz row containerlevel3 block_A2uGW9wfh3chajRB1xUz xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0">
                        <div class="LayoutWrapper">
                            <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel4 block_Mg6zpS xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0">
                                <% $breakpoint_xs=4 $breakpoint_sm=4 $breakpoint_md=3 $viewport_xs=34 $viewport_sm=34 $viewport_md=25 %>
                                    <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel5 block_ACgWE3dl6P7aMyLEiZpA xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0">
                                        <% $breakpoint_xs=4 $breakpoint_sm=4 $breakpoint_md=3 $viewport_xs=34 $viewport_sm=34 $viewport_md=25 %>
                                            <div class="LayoutWrapper">&nbsp;</div>
                                            <!--LayoutWrapper-->
                                    </div>
                                    <% $breakpoint_xs=4 $breakpoint_sm=4 $breakpoint_md=3 $viewport_xs=34 $viewport_sm=34 $viewport_md=25 %>
                            </div>
                            <% $breakpoint_xs=12 $breakpoint_sm=12 $breakpoint_md=12 $viewport_xs=100 $viewport_sm=100 $viewport_md=100 %>
                                <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-2 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-2 col-md-2 hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel4 block_Av9VlZFW9do3L9Sl3UHt xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0">
                                    <% $breakpoint_xs=4 $breakpoint_sm=4 $breakpoint_md=2 $viewport_xs=34 $viewport_sm=34 $viewport_md=17 %>
                                        &nbsp;</div>
                                <% $breakpoint_xs=12 $breakpoint_sm=12 $breakpoint_md=12 $viewport_xs=100 $viewport_sm=100 $viewport_md=100 %>
                                    <div class="VerticalContainer LayoutContainer  col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-3 col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-md-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm containerlevel4 block_AznTXorPnQUat83KnXDa xs-pt-0 xs-pr-0 xs-pb-0 xs-pl-0 sm-pt-0 sm-pr-0 sm-pb-0 sm-pl-0 md-pt-0 md-pr-0 md-pb-0 md-pl-0 last">
                                        <% $breakpoint_xs=4 $breakpoint_sm=4 $breakpoint_md=3 $viewport_xs=34 $viewport_sm=34 $viewport_md=25 %>
                                            <%$LAYOUT_block_id='20'%>
```

Comment: You can make something stay at the top with CSS position - https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick it on top, use `position:sticky;` and add the id.